# Custom Element Index stopped working after Update

Tags: craft3, templating, elementtype, index

So we had an "old" Craft 3.1.* instance that i needed to update. Which is now running on Craft 3.7.20.

This instance does have a Module which introduces a new ElementType with its own custom CP Index Page and crud twig templates.

The Problem is now that after updating, the index page is no longer loading and displaying the entries. And i only have one console error to guide me.

Is there a documentation that i did not read or maybe someone has an idea where to start looking.

- [[Twig Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNR1n.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNR1n.png)
- [[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK6So.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK6So.png)
- [[CP: Befor Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFxOx.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFxOx.png)
- [[CP: After Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHbsA.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHbsA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my Problem and hopefully this will help other people in the feature.

My problem was inside my custom CP Panel indexpage twig [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNR1n.png).
In an earlier version of Craft you could simply overwrite the `{% block header %}` and place custom action buttons for my own save and edit actions.

But after a certain update the layout inside the Craft CP was reworked and this no longer worked.

- Now this is simply done by overwriting the dedicated {% block actionButtons %} to achive this goal.

#### !overwriting the {% block header %} breaks crafts elementindex view!